# How to position multiple dialogs on the same page with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building an in-app walkthrough with Vuetify. And I need to be able to define the position of many dialogs on the same page. I am able to custom position one dialog with this CSS overriding the default:

```
>>> .v-dialog {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0px !important;
  right: 45px !important;
}
```

And I've tried to use custom classes, with the same css, but they won't work. I'm having to redefine the built in class, and so it will end up placing ALL the dialogs in the same spot which isn't what I want.

Comment: Use `content-class="..."`, as opposed to just `class="..."`, for your custom classes then the CSS will be applied.

Comment: @ToddT what library are you using?

Comment: @seantunwin yes!! that was totally it